# Integral of involving Airy function without using its antiderivative

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Inspired by my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/262805/7266), I am interested in evaluating the following definite integral
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{dz}{\mathop{\rm Ai}^2(z)} =1 $$
without using its antiderivate.
 At first, it seems we need to have $c\geq 0$ but as I will point out below, any $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathop{\rm Ai}(c) \neq 0$ will give the same result.

The integral can be solved using the antiderivative $ \frac{\pi\mathop{\rm Bi}(z)}{\mathop{\rm Ai}(z)}$ together with the well-known [asymptotic expansion for Ai and Bi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function#Asymptotic_formulae) as I pointed out in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/267899/7266) to the question.

All the zeros of the Airy function lie on the negative real axis. 
The curious fact why the above mentioned result holds for almost all $c$ is that all the residues at the corresponding poles of $\mathop{\rm Ai}^{-2}(z)$ vanish. The reason is that due to Airy's differential equation $\mathop{\rm Ai}''(z) - z \mathop{\rm Ai}(z) =0$ every zero of Ai comes together with a vanishing second derivative. Thus for any pole $z^*$ of $\mathop{\rm Ai}^{-2}(z)$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{\mathop{\rm Ai}^{2}(z)} =\frac{1}{[\alpha (z- z^*) + \mathcal{O}(z-z^*)^3 ]^2} = \frac{1}{\alpha^2 (z- z^*)^2} + \mathcal{O}(1) $$
and the residue vanishes.

My question is if/how the definite integral can be solved without resorting to the antiderivative?

Comment: Hello Fabian. We are meeting a very similar expression while studying the phase transitions of directed graphs. Can you point to a research of yours, perhaps a preprint or some relevant research? Our work is to appear soon, so it would be exciting to point out some non-obvious links, and I will share the preprint when we finish.

Comment: @SergeyDovgal: interesting that this question comes up in your research. From my side, this question was inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262805/evaluate-a-definite-integral-involving-airy-functions) as it is a remarable result that defies a simple explanation in terms of complex integrals and the residue theorem. So I am sorry to tell you that there is no research of mine which I can point you to.

Comment: @djws We have a square of the derivative of the Airy function in the denominator, but the principle is the same. What is funny is that after discovering Knessl's paper which is pointed out in the commentaries, his solutions in terms of contour integrals of Airy functions is even more similar to what we obtain from a totally different perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is given in the appendix of the following paper: Knessl, C. Exact and Asymptotic Solutions to a PDE That Arises in Time-Dependent Queues. *Adv. Appl. Prob.*, **32**(1) 256--283, 2000.

Let me describe this solution and highlight some subtle points.

${\rm Ai}(z)$ has different asymptotic approximations for large $|z|$ valid in different regions of the complex plane. We are going to use
$$
{\rm Ai}(z) \sim \frac{1}{2 \pi^{\frac{1}{2}} z^{\frac{1}{4}}}
\left( e^{-\frac{2}{3} z^{\frac{3}{2}}} + {\rm i} e^{\frac{2}{3} z^{\frac{3}{2}}} \right) \;,
$$
which is valid as $|z| \to \infty$ assuming $\frac{\pi}{3} < {\rm arg}(z) < \frac{5 \pi}{3}$,
to replace
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{{\rm Ai}^2(z)} \;,
$$
with
$$
g(z) = \frac{4 \pi z^{\frac{1}{2}}}
{\left( e^{-\frac{2}{3} z^{\frac{3}{2}}} + {\rm i} e^{\frac{2}{3} z^{\frac{3}{2}}} \right)^2} \;.
$$

We need to consider the following three contours (with which we will take $R \to \infty$):
\begin{eqnarray}
C_1 &=& \{ {\rm i} s \}_{s = -R}^{s = R} \;, \\
C_2 &=& \{ R e^{{\rm i} \theta} \}_{\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta = \frac{3 \pi}{2}} \;, \\
C_3 &=& \{ e^{\frac{4 {\rm i} \pi}{3}} s \}_{s = R}^{s = 0} \cup
\{ e^{\frac{2 {\rm i} \pi}{3}} s \}_{s = 0}^{s = R} \;.
\end{eqnarray}

The given problem is to evaluate
$$
I \equiv \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi {\rm i}} \int_{C_1} f(z) \,dz \;.
$$
By Cauchy's residue theorem,
since the residues of the singularities of $f(z)$ are all zero, we have
$$
\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi {\rm i}} \int_{C_1 \cup C_2} f(z) \,dz = 0 \;,
$$
thus
$$
I = - \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi {\rm i}} \int_{C_2} f(z) \,dz \;.
$$
In view of the asymptotic approximation, it follows that
$$
I = - \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi {\rm i}} \int_{C_2} g(z) \,dz \;.
$$
Again by Cauchy's residue theorem,
since the residues of the singularities of $g(z)$ are all zero, we have
$$
\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi {\rm i}} \int_{C_1 \cup C_2} g(z) \,dz = 0 \;,
$$
thus
$$
I = \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi {\rm i}} \int_{C_1} g(z) \,dz \;.
$$
Finally we may deform $C_1$ to $C_3$, i.e.,
$$
I = \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi {\rm i}} \int_{C_3} g(z) \,dz \;.
$$

We can evaluate this integral by explicitly parametrizing $C_3$.
For the first part of $C_3$, $z = e^{\frac{4 \pi {\rm i}}{3}} s$,
where $s$ ranges from $\infty$ to $0$, and note that, in particular,
$z^{3/2} = s^{3/2}$.
For the second part of $C_3$, $z = e^{\frac{2 \pi {\rm i}}{3}} s$,
where $s$ ranges from $0$ to $\infty$, and here
$z^{3/2} = -s^{3/2}$. We have

$$
I = \frac{2}{{\rm i}} \int_\infty^0
\frac{s^{\frac{1}{2}}}
{\left( e^{-\frac{2}{3} s^{\frac{3}{2}}} + {\rm  i} e^{\frac{2}{3} s^{\frac{3}{2}}} \right)^2} \,ds +
\frac{2}{{\rm i}} \int_0^\infty
\frac{-s^{\frac{1}{2}}}
{\left( e^{\frac{2}{3} s^{\frac{3}{2}}} + {\rm  i} e^{-\frac{2}{3} s^{\frac{3}{2}}} \right)^2} \,ds \;.
$$

By multiplying and dividing each integral by the square of  the complex conjugate of the term appearing in the denominator (the usual trick to make the denominator real-valued) and combining the integrals and simplifying we arrive at
\begin{eqnarray}
I &=& 8 \int_0^\infty \frac{s^{\frac{1}{2}}}
{\left( e^{\frac{4}{3} s^{\frac{3}{2}}} + e^{-\frac{4}{3} s^{\frac{3}{2}}} \right)^2} \,ds \\
&=& \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{{\rm cosh}^2(u)} \,du \\
&=& {\rm tanh}(u) \big|_0^\infty \\
&=& 1 \;,
\end{eqnarray}
as required.

Comment: It is indeed very subtle. What confuses me a bit is that on first sight the integral of $f$ (or of $g$ for that matter) along the contour $C_2$ vanishes because $g\to 0$ sufficiently fast. What is wrong with my argument?

Comment: That confused me too. But recall ${\rm Ai}(z) \to 0$ as $z \to -\infty$. Thus $f(z) \to \infty$ as $z \to -\infty$. Also $g(-t) = \frac{2^{3/2} \pi t^{1/2}}{1 + {\rm sin}(4/3 t^{3/2})} \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: but still it is a single point and away from the real axis the function approaches 0 exponentially! So I guess one can think about the $g$ at infinity to be something like a $\delta$ function.

Comment: By the way: how did you find this paper?

Comment: I already knew about the paper as the main problem there of Brownian motion with simple time-dependent drift arose in my research.